# How to define object in type script interface

Tags: typescript

I am very new to Type Script. I am wondering whether there is a way to tell that in the interface "IIndex" SystemStatus  is an object that has Data and DataUrl as properties. Currently it is showing that the SystemStatus is undefined.

```
interface IIndex extends ng.IScope {
    TotalRequestedJobCount: number;
    TotalScheduledJobCount: number;

    SystemStatus: {
        Data: any;
        DataUrl: string;
    }

    refreshSystemStatus: EmptyFunc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already declaring an `IIndex` interface that has a `SystemStatus` property having two properties of its own.  You can use it like this.

```
type EmptyFunc = any;

module ng {
    export interface IScope { }
}

interface IIndex extends ng.IScope{
    TotalRequestedJobCount: number;
    TotalScheduledJobCount: number;

    SystemStatus:{
        Data: any;
        DataUrl: string;
    }
    refreshSystemStatus: EmptyFunc;
}


var obj: IIndex = {
    TotalRequestedJobCount: 1,
    TotalScheduledJobCount: 2,
    refreshSystemStatus: "foo",
    SystemStatus: {
        Data: 1337,
        DataUrl: "asdf"
    } 
}
```

If you're having problems using your interface, the problem is somewhere else.  This code looks fine.